# "You must add a reference to assembly" compiler error in weird case

Tags: c#, overloading

I have two applications App1 and App2. App1 added a reference to App2 and App2 added a reference to `System.Drawing`.

In App2 there's a function with two overloads, the first one is *protected* and has a parameter from `System.Drawing.Bitmap` and the second one is *public* has an integer parameter.

```
namespace App1Namespace
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            App2Namespace.StaticClass.Func(4);
```

---

```
namespace App2Namespace
{
    public class StaticClass
    {
        protected static void Func(System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmapParam) { }
        public static void Func(int intParam) { }
```

When the App1 is built, the following compile time error will be thrown:

> Error 1   The type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' is defined in an assembly
>   that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Although `Func` which has `Bimap` param is protected, the App1 needs having a reference to `System.Drawing`.

The questions are that why does App1 need `System.Drawing`? and why this error appears only when the second overload is called and doesn't appear when another overload (for example with two parameters) is called?

Note: When the first overload becomes private the error will disappear.

Comment: Don't you mean "When App1 is built, the compile time error will be thrown"

Comment: @ Ash: Yes, it's App1. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The reason is likely because you are declaring `StaticClass` as a regular class.  So it is possible to override the class in any referencing assemblies (thus why using `protected` would almost make sense for a static method).  If all the methods are truly static methods, then make the class itself static and change the scope from `protected` to `internal` or `private`.

Answer (score 0):

It may simply be that it needs a reference, because since your App2Namespace.StaticClass.Func could be inherited from (since it's protected) in a class in the App1 namespace.  If that were to happen, it would also need a reference to System.Drawing.

Comment: I don't think so, because if you didn't call the overload which has an integer param then, no errors will appear

Comment: That's quite interesting. I've came across the same error in VS.net, but just always added the reference as it stated, never questioned it.